# take mysql backup in ubuntu openfire

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed ubunto os in my system and also i have installed the openfire in that system.And i have installed spark chat  also.I have created the users and its working perfectly.we can chat with another perfectly. but now i need to take the database backup. Am going to use Mysql so anyone please tell me how to take the backup in openfire.

I need to take database backup.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific to openfire in taking the backup. Install phpmyadmin

sudo aptitude install phpmyadmin

This will complete the installation.

Now you need to goto

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Login using your mysql root as username and password

Take the backup of the db as usual :)